# prevent external access to mp3 files

Tags: .htaccess, mp3

I am writing and rewriting my htaccess and does not work properly, it is still possible to listen to my mp3 files from an external website with a direct link:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^frenchspanishonline.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http\:\/\/www\.\ frenchspanishonline\.com\/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?frenchspanishonline.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|mp3|css)$ - [NC,F,L]

order allow,deny
deny from atirchad.com
deny from 66.96.144.190
allow from all
```

I managed to block swf files but not mp3 ones, don't know why!
If I write a specific Rewriterule to the site I want to block, it blocks my own website!
any help?

Answer (score 1):

The truth is, you can control it, but only in a **limited way**, unfortunately.

Your current solution relies on http referer header - which may and mey not be sent. It's up to end browsers to decide if they will provide you tracking information or not.

Thus, there is no 100% working solution.

---

The problem here is probabkly that the first rewrite condition is true and so it won't jump to the next one.

Comment: Agreed, logic based on referrer is not 100% reliable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cpanel, there is "HotLink Protect" feature. If you really want to use following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://jmsliu.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://jmsliu.com$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ - [F,NC]
```

At least, it works for me. I hope it can help you as well.

Thanks

Comment: thank you, actually the code I use is able to block images and also swf files but not mp3 and this is what I would like to block too and I don't know why just a part of the code works.

Answer (score 0):

I found that

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} atirchad\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

blocks mp3 in Chrome, Firefox and IE but not in Safari.